# How can I add a legend to a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot, and this is the code used to generate it:

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(MO, -log(GC1), -log(GC2))
colnames(df) <- c("MO", "IPs -> DLPFc", "DLPFc -> IPs")

ggplot(df, aes(x = MO, y = -log(GC1)), geom = c("point", "smooth")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = -log(GC1), linetype = "IPs -> DLPFc")) + 
  labs(x = "Model Order", y = "-Log(P-Value)", title = "Granger Causality") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.3, col='green') + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = -log(GC2), linetype = "DLPFc -> IPs"), col = 'red')
```

How do get a correct legend specifying the the lines with the correct directions? Thanks!!

Comment: It would be easier to melt and then plot like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364641/adding-legend-and-structuring-data-for-ggplot) q/a

Comment: Thank you! I've tried a line such as this:  data <- melt(df, id.vars = "MO", measure.vars = c("-log(GC1)", "-log(GC2)"))
But it has not worked...